# Issue regarding react sometimes not loading updated usestate until clicked again

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I've been having a problem with a personal project I'm working on with react where I attempt to add an item to a cart and usually it adds it normally, but occasionally it will skip visually updating the cart on click and add it in a later click. Sometimes this happens with multiple items in a row, sometimes not at all and closing and opening the cart always visually updates it to what should be the latest contents. I'm think I'm misunderstanding or misusing a state value but I have no idea where or why. I'm still kind of new to react so any help would be appreciated, I haven't been able to figure this out for days. the relevant code is as follows:

```
export default function Cart(props) {

    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
    const [addedItemClick, setAddedItemClick] = useState(false);
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [cartChanged, setCartChanged] = useState(false);
    const [height, setHeight] = useState();


    const loadCartData = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/allCartItems`);
            setLoaded(true);
            setCartItems(result.data)
  

        } catch (error) {
        }
    }

    const renderCartInv = (cartItem, index) =>{

        return(
            <div>
            <Stack key={index}>
                <Item>
                    <SingleCartItem cartItem={cartItem} />
                    <Button onClick={()=>handleRemoveItem(cartItem.id)}>remove</Button>
                </Item>
            </Stack>
            </div>
        )

    }
    
    function handleRemoveItem(id){
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/deleteCartEntity?id=${id}`)
        loadCartData();

    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        const handle = subscribe(AddToShoppingCartEvent, (eventReturn) =>{
            setCartChanged(true);
            setAddedItemClick(eventReturn.buttonClicked)
        });
        return function cleanup(){
            setAddedItemClick(false)
            handle.unsubscribe();
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if(cartChanged === true){
            loadCartData();
            setCartChanged(false)
    }
    }, [cartChanged])

    useEffect(() => {
            loadCartData();
            setTimeout(() => {
                setHeight(document.getElementsByClassName('card_grid').item(0).children.item(0).clientHeight * 4)
               }, 20)
    }, [])

    return (props.trigger) ? (
    <Box className="cart_popup" height={height}>
        <Box className="cart_popup_data">
        {cartItems ? cartItems.map(renderCartInv)  : null}
        </Box>
    </Box>
    ) : "";
}
```

I tried using functional updates for setting states assuming it was using an older state when rendering but it didn't help, I attempted to use small timeouts to give the promise time to return assuming it may have been causing a problem. the fact that its only happening on occasion is making it hard to me to even understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with API calls then you have to write a `async function` with `await` keyword.

***Let's Refactor your code:***

```
export default function Cart(props) {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

  const loadCartData = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/allCartItems`);
      setCartItems(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error In LoadCartData', error);
    }
  };
  async function handleRemoveItem(id) {
    await axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/deleteCartEntity?id=${id}`);
    document.getElementById(id).remove();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadCartData();
  }, []);

  return props.trigger ? (
    <Box className="cart_popup">
      <Box className="cart_popup_data">
        {cartItems
          ? cartItems.map((cartItem, index) => (
              <Stack id={cartItem.id} key={index}>
                <Item>
                  <SingleCartItem cartItem={cartItem} />
                  <Button onClick={() => handleRemoveItem(cartItem.id)}>
                    remove
                  </Button>
                </Item>
              </Stack>
            ))
          : null}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  ) : (
    ''
  );
}
```

I hope it will works❤️❤️